# Making UIScrollView bounce when cursor left off at certain position

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Is there a way to make scroll view bounce and settle if you stop the scroll between two elements in the scroll view?

Comment: Yes, it's called pagination, you basically simply need to set the contentSize and then set *self.pagingEnabled = YES; (or True if using Swift)*

Comment: It worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called **Pagination**, you basically need to set the **contentSize** and then set `self.pagingEnabled = YES;` in *Objective C* (or `self.pagingEnabled = true` if using *Swift*)